# Function that expects an UnsafeMutablePointer<Type>!

Tags: swift, cocoa, opengl

I'm trying to render an offscreen image with OpenGL following the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_offscreen/opengl_offscreen.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH403-SW16) (written in Objective-C). I've created a simple Cocoa CLI project and added this code as a primer within the main.swift file but I can't manage to compile it:

```
import Foundation
import AGL

var framebuffer: GLuint

glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &framebuffer)
```

With this code I get the following message from the compiler: `Address of variable 'framebuffer' taken before it is initialized`.

The signature of the OpenGL function is `func glGenFramebuffersEXT(_ n: GLsizei, _ framebuffers: UnsafeMutablePointer<GLuint>!)`.

When trying with `var framebuffer: GLuint = 0` the program simply crashes.

How should I initialize the `framebuffer`variable to make this work?

Comment: `var framebuffer: GLuint = 0` would be the correct approach, as far as the type system is concerned. I don't know enough about the function to know about what what kind value it expects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All OpenGL APIs need to be run in a certain OpenGL rendering context.
I haven't tried much with OpenGL on macOS, but this code runs without crashing:

```
import OpenGL.GL
import AppKit

let attributes: [NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute] = [
    NSOpenGLPFAAllRenderers,
    NSOpenGLPFAAllowOfflineRenderers,
    //...
    0 //terminator
].map{NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute($0)}
if
    let format = NSOpenGLPixelFormat(attributes: attributes),
    let context = NSOpenGLContext(format: format, share: nil)
{
    context.makeCurrentContext()

    var framebuffer: GLuint = 0 //<- this is the right way to work with `UnsafeMutablePointer<GLuint>`.
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer)
    //...
}
```

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the documentation and thought offscreen rendering didn't need a rendering context.

Comment: @iamdto, in fact, I have re-read the Apple's document several times, and it's not clear enough that we need some rendering context even if we do offscreen rendering. And also unclear what is the best way to create an offscreen rendering context. Better write an improvement request with the Apple's [Bug Reporter](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).